# mysql and or query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a search query, where a user can search by name or course or year or member, any one of above and also the user cam make a search with all the field or any number of field, e.g.;-as only with name & course.

How it is possible? I don't want to make different query, can it be possible with a single query? now my query is:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM fsb_profile 
    WHERE profile_name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."' 
    AND profile_member= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' 
    AND profile_year= '".$_REQUEST['year']."' 
    AND profile_course='".$_REQUEST['course']."' 
     OR profile_name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."' 
     OR profile_member= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' 
     OR profile_year= '".$_REQUEST['year']."' 
     OR profile_course='".$_REQUEST['course']."'";
```

but it's not running, it's only searching by any one of the field, how it is possible?

Comment: You have been asking the same questions over and over again. Do yourself a favor and study a bit of SQL and Boolean Algebra (and when you're done don't forget to read about SQL Injection vulnerabilities).

Comment: Sounds like you are only going to need to filter the three fields using OR clauses.
Can you post some sample data and what output you expect from a particular search query? Will help us to help you :)

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape` or prepared statements; or be ready to face [exploits of a mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql and or query run together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237397/mysql-and-or-query-run-together)

Answer (score 11):

If you're mixing AND with OR in a where clause, then it's useful to use brackets to indicate exactly how the combination should be expressed: (A AND B) OR C is not the same as A AND (B OR C). SQL will interpret A AND B OR C (without any brackets) in its own manner, but not necessarily how you might expect (or intend) it to be interpreted.

e.g.

```
WHERE Likes Soccer AND ( Likes Pizza OR Likes Whiskey )
```

is looking for a person who likes Soccer and likes either Pizza or Whiskey; so it will pick Soccer-lovers who like Pizza, Soccer-lovers who like Whiskey, Soccer-lovers who like both Pizza and Whiskey

```
WHERE ( Likes Soccer AND  Likes Pizza ) OR Likes Whiskey
```

is looking for a person who likes both Soccer and Pizza, or a person who likes Whiskey; so it will pick Soccer-lovers who must also like Pizza, or Whiskey-lovers, or Soccer-lovers who must also like Pizza but may also like Whiskey

Answer (score 1):

Just use `or` then your query will work.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM fsb_profile 
    WHERE profile_name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."' 
     OR profile_member= '".$_REQUEST['type']."' 
     OR profile_year= '".$_REQUEST['year']."' 
     OR profile_course='".$_REQUEST['course']."'";
```

Not tested.